# bootstrap datetimepicker installation

Tags: jquery-ui, bootstrap-datetimepicker

I am using bootstrap datetimepicker version 3. Here datetimepicker de-faulty taking current date and time. But in next version this problem is resolved. So I will try to use Eonasdan bootstrap datetimepicker version v4. For that what are the js and css files I have include in my jsp page?

Answer (score 1):

Check manual installation guide [here](https://github.com/Eonasdan/bootstrap-datetimepicker/wiki/Installation#manual).

You must include:

- jQuery
- Moment.js
- Bootstrap + collapse + transitions

So the files needed would be:

- bootstrap.min.js
- bootstrap.min.css
- moment-with-locales.js
- bootstrap-datetimepicker.css
- bootstrap-datetimepicker.js

Check this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/33Le4k93/) for a working example.

HTML:

```
<br/>
<!-- padding for jsfiddle -->
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
         <h6>datetimepicker1</h6>

        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="input-group date" id="datetimepicker1">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" />  <span class="input-group-addon"><span class="glyphicon-calendar glyphicon"></span></span>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

JS:

```
$('#datetimepicker1').datetimepicker();
```

Comment: It has showing the following error.....                                                                                 
:8443/ScorpioPoolWebAppPanp/resources/fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.ttf:1 GET https://localhost:8443/ScorpioPoolWebAppPanp/resources/fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.ttf

Comment: GET https://localhost:8443/ScorpioPoolWebAppPanp/resources/fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.woff

Comment: From the bootstrap downloaded files, include the related font files in /resources/fonts in your project

Comment: I'm having similar issues with newer versions of the javascript libraries: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32026039

Comment: how can I include bootstrap-datetimepicker.js using npm?