# Bootstrap datetimepicker installation/configuration

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, jquery-ui, bootstrap-datetimepicker

I'm having some issues with a basic configuration of the [eonasdan bootstrap datetimepicker](http://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/).

I created a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/gregmattes/hnLrds43/) using the code from their [basic setup instructions](http://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/#minimum-setup) to show my configuration. I see another [Stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29001753) on this topic that has another [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/33Le4k93/) with older versions of the same plugins. The two fiddles look similar, but mine doesn't work.

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class='col-sm-6'>
            <div class="form-group">
                <div class='input-group date' id='datetimepicker1'>
                    <input type='text' class="form-control" />
                    <span class="input-group-addon">
                        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
                    </span>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(function () {
                $('#datetimepicker1').datetimepicker();
            });
        </script>
    </div>
</div>
```

Why doesn't the datetime picker in my fiddle work?

Comment: I think the fiddle you linked to is empty. Maybe you forgot to save?

Comment: Can you see the fiddle now?

Comment: Yes, I can see it now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you run your fiddle while inspecting the console you will see the following error:

```
uncaught exception: bootstrap-datetimepicker requires Moment.js to be loaded first
```

So it's simply a matter of the order in which the scripts are loaded. [**This**](https://jsfiddle.net/_abl/bdabvcLy/) is exactly the same fiddle, except `bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.js` is loaded last, and it works.

Just take care of loading the resources in the right order, or use a dependency management tool to sort it out for you.